# Python cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' objects

Tags: python, datetime

I have this code, but I got an error and could not find a soulution to the problem. I was trying to get a time and then plus i hour becuase i live in europe.

Here is my code:
`plus_one_hour = "21:00:00" + timedelta(hours=2)`

And the error:
`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' objects`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert your string to datetime object.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
plus_one_hour = datetime.datetime.strptime("21:00:00", "%H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
print(plus_one_hour.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

**Output:**

```
23:00:00
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks for the code, i dont know if it was me trying to print it out or your code. But anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: i try to this script but not work